# Retrieving Computer Names That Produced an Error From Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm working on speeding the execution of a script and long story short, the core of it would look similar to this (minus `Measure-Command`):

```
$devices = Get-Content "list.txt"

Measure-Command{
try{
    $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $devices -ScriptBlock {
                Get-LocalUser |  Select-Object -Property @{N="Computer"; E={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, 
                Name, Enabled, PasswordChangeableDate, PasswordExpires, UserMayChangePassword, 
                PasswordRequired, PasswordLastSet, LastLogon, 
                        @{n="Groups"; E={
                            $user = $_
                            Get-LocalGroup | Where-Object {  $user.SID -in ($_ | Get-LocalGroupMember | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "SID") } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name"
                        }}
            } 2>> "errors.txt"
}catch{
    Write-Host "Uh oh..." -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host $Error[0]
}
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is, in the case of an error on one of the devices, I want to store that device name in a separate file. In the past I was doing all of this process via a `foreach` loop with `try/catch`, which made this part very easy. I'm looking to avoid that with this solution.
Right now, I'm using `2>> "errors.txt"` courtesy of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/924jwq/logging_connection_failures_with_invokecommand/e336pme?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) post, but this records the full error, which I don't want. Example:

> [EXAMPLE DEVICE] Connecting to remote server EXAMPLE DEVICE failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
> request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer EXAMPLE DEVICE. Verify that
> the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
> + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (EXAMPLE DEVICE:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken

I'd like the **only** record the name of the device (in this case "EXAMPLE DEVICE") in the file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried launching this with `-AsJob`? Each block will then provide its output separately, you'll then be able to include only the relevant stuff in that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle is to set `-ErrorActions SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Errs`.

This enables the program to flow normally without bleeding red errors all over the screen.  Then you can look at the error records stored in `$Errs` to report on which machines had issues.  In your case `$Errs.TagrgetObject`.

Demo might be something like

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock { "Whatever..." } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Errs

# PostOp Check which machines had errors:
$Errs.TargetObject
```

This should return:

```
MrBogus
MrsBogus
```

Of course, if you want to format that more robustly you can do any arbitrary processing on the error records.